# When including external xml file, LayoutInflater throws RuntimeException: "You must supply a layout_width attribute."

Tags: android, listview, runtimeexception

I'm trying to include a ScrollView (upgrade_content.xml) containing a ListView in my Activity's XML layout file (upgrades.xml). When I include the external file using `<include layout="@layout/upgrades_content"/>`, I get a RuntimeException with the message "You must supply a layout_width attribute."

If I copy the code from upgrade_content.xml and paste it directly into upgrades.xml, it works fine.

upgrades.xml (This throws the exception):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/upgrades_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_screen_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/upgrades_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

upgrades_content.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <!-- Activity Title -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/upgrades_title_text"
                android:text="@string/upgrade_store_string"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TitleTextSize"
                style="@style/ActivityTitleTextStyle" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!--  Upgrades List -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@drawable/old_paper_bg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/OldPaperScrollViewMargin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/OldPaperScrollViewMargin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/OldPaperScrollViewMargin"
            android:padding="@dimen/OldPaperScrollViewPadding">

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

UpgradeActivity.java:

```
public class UpgradeActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.upgrades);

        setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
                R.array.upgrade_string_array, 
                R.layout.upgrade_layout_list_item));
    }
}
```

upgrade_layout_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/LabelTextSize" />
```

EDIT:
The RuntimeException thrown by this code doesn't cause a Force Close, so I might have just been a little too liberal in which exceptions I set Eclipse to catch.

Comment: Can you show the included layout please?

Comment: Make sure you declare layout_width in the ScrollView layout

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pressed Enter while putting some tags in, so it asked the question before I was finished writing it. Now it's done.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Did you try cleaning your project (`Project -> Clean ..` inside eclipse)? That forces the regeneration of all resources from scratch.

Comment: Just tried cleaning. Same result.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to answer, but I want to save people the effort. It seems that while this throws an exception, it does not cause a Force Close, so it shouldn't be a problem. I just won't set Eclipse to catch RuntimeExceptions.

Comment: This has nothing to do with you question, but why are you using both fill_parent and match_parent?  They are both the same thing, match_parent is the new name for fill_parent in api 8 and higher.

Comment: Because I had yet to be educated about that :-) Thanks. I always wondered why they basically did the same thing. I tend to switch between fill_parent, match_parent, and wrap_content to see how it affects views. When I find something that works (or doesn't break) I usually keep whatever I put. I'll make sure to change those.

Answer (score 0):

try to specify the layout height and width in `upgrade.xml` under your `<include>` tag like this:

```
<include 
    layout="@layout/upgrades_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Put the width and height values to whatever fill your need: `fill_parent` or `wrap_content`

Comment: I did try that and it still throws the exception. If I set Eclipse to not catch RuntimeExceptions, the app doesn't Force Close, so it shouldn't be a problem. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried your code without styles and dimensions you've set because I don't have your `string.xml` file. So I tried with common values for text size,margin and also removed background color just for test purpose and the code work fine here, no exception thrown at all. So would you give your `string.xml` here? I will also test with your values to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was just catching all RuntimeExceptions instead of just uncaught exceptions. The app doesn't crash so I think the exception is caught and handled successfully by Android.